# Posting dropdown and text clone elements to PHPMailer

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I am trying to create a mailform in which we can provide accurate quotes for building projects. Right now I have the form with several dropdowns with additional text inputs so a customer can choose a style and include their desired size. I would like to get it so that by the click of a button a specific div including both the style dropdown and size text will be cloned and post the additional styles and sizes they input. My current script looks like this

```
 <div class="windowdiv">
    <label for="windowselect"> Type </label>
       <select type="select" name="windowselect">
            <option value="None"> None </option>
            <option value="vinyl single hung"> Vinyl Single Hung - w/ J Channel </option>
            <option value="vinyl slider"> Vinyl slider - w/ J Channel</option>
       </select><br>
    <label for="wdsize">Size (W'xH')</label>
        <input type="size" name="wdsize" placeholder="W'xH'">
 </div>
 <button type="button" class="button" id="windowbtn">Add Another window</button>


<script>
  $("#windowbtn").click(function () {

  $('.windowdiv:first').clone().removeClass('windowdiv').addClass('addwindow').insertAfter(".windowdiv");

});    
</script>
```

And I'm just using a simple php $_POST

```
<?php
    $windowselect = $_POST['windowselect'];

    $email_message .= "Windows: ".clean_string($windowselect)."\n";
?>
```

Also I am pretty new to coding so the more "spelled out" the better. 
I appreciate any and all help!